# Fusion table authentication lost when writing special character to a table field

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I am very new on google app scripts and fusion tables. I am developing a CRM app to my company and I am using google sites, google app scripts and fusion table to do that.
I am also using an example from the book "Google Script - Enterprise Application Essentials" from O'Reilly to build my app.
I am using Fusion table as a database to my project, and I run the function doOAuth() to give permission to everyone to perform the actions on fusion table.(See code below containing doOAuth code that i got from the book).
The app works fine for every command i make to the fusion table. I am able to read the content of the table, i am able to make a search on that as well, but when it comes to write new data or update existing data on the table I am facing an annoying problem.
I have some textboxes on my app on which I insert some datas, and those datas are written to the table, no problem so far, when I add common text to those textboxes I have no problem when updating data or inserting data to the fusion table. But when I add any special character to those textbox like: á,ã,à,ä,é,õ,í and so on, I receive a message telling me that it is needed authotization to perform that process. But I already gave the authorization. It seems that the authorization is lost. And even if I run the doOAuth() function again, the permission is not given. The insertFusionObj() and the writeFusionObj() functions (listed on the code below) seems to have a problem when their parameters are special characters. I don't know if that is a problem from the functions or if that is a fusion table insert and update problem.
I would really appreciate if someone could help me on that problem, because my app is intended to be used in portuguese language which have some special characters and when the person responsible for adding information to the app uses it, he will probably use special characters on insertion and update of the fusion table.

I am looking forward for some help .
Best Regards
Rafael Setti Nogueira

Code:

```
    /**
     * ---FusionService---
     *
     *  Copyright (c) 2011 James Ferreira
     *
     *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     *  limitations under the License.
     */

    /**
     * FusionService 
     * @author James Ferreira
     * @documentation http://goo.gl/pBSvF
     *
     * @requires Script Insert ID: ?????
     *           ObjService http://goo.gl/JdEHW
     *
     * @requires The Fusion Table ID MUST be set in a Script property. 
     *           This will allow you to change it at anytime using
     *           ScriptProperties.setProperty('FUSION_ID', '<your ID>'); 
     *
     *
     * Search for records in a Fusion Table 
     *
     * @params {string}  target   Quoted column name(s) ('First Name', 'Last Name') OR (*) for all 
     * @params {string}  where    valid statement see http://goo.gl/SkHI1
     *                            'Last Name' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE 'Ferr' 
     *                             AND 'First Name' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE 'J'" 
     *
     * @returns {array}           [[headers],[match row],[match row]...]
     *                            If no match returns []
     */
    function searchFusion(target, where){
      var values = [];
      if (target == '*'){
        var headers = getFusionHeaders();
        for(var i in headers){
          values.push("'"+headers[i]+"'"); 
        }   
      }else{
        values.push(target); 
      }
      var arrayResult = fusionRequest("get", "SELECT "+values.toString()+",ROWID FROM "+
                                      FUSION_ID+" WHERE "+ where).split(/\n/);
      for (var i in arrayResult){
        arrayResult[i] = arrayResult[i].split(/,/); 
      }
      arrayResult.splice(arrayResult.length-1, 1);
      return arrayResult;
    }

    /**
     * Updates a record in the Fusion table
     * Note: fusionObj must contain rowid of Fusion table record
     *
     * @params  {object}  fusionObj  object with properties from cameled column names
     * @returns {string}             OK if successful
     */
    function writeFusionObj(fusionObj){
      var values = [];
      var headers = getFusionHeaders();   
      for(var i in headers){
        if (fusionObj[camelString(headers[i])] != undefined)
        values.push("'"+headers[i] +"'='"+fusionObj[camelString(headers[i])]+"'"); 
      }  
     return fusionRequest("post", "UPDATE "+FUSION_ID+" SET "+values.toString()+
                          " WHERE ROWID = '"+fusionObj.rowid+"'") 
    }

    /**
     * Add a new record to a Fusion table
     *
     * @params  {object}  fusionObj  object with properties from cameled column names
     * @returns {integer}            rowid useful for unique ID of record
     */
    function insertFusionObj(fusionObj){
      var values = [];
      var columns =[];
      var headers = getFusionHeaders(); 

      for(var i in headers){
        columns.push("'"+headers[i] +"'");
        values.push("'"+fusionObj[camelString(headers[i])]+"'"); 
      }  
      return parseInt(fusionRequest("post", "INSERT INTO "+FUSION_ID+
                        " ("+columns.toString()+") VALUES ("+values.toString()+")").substring(5));
    }

    /**
     * Get the Fusion row ID for a given column header and unique value
     *
     * @returns {integer}    Fusion ROWID for record
     */
    function getFusionROWID(header, key){
     return parseInt(fusionRequest("get", "SELECT ROWID FROM "+FUSION_ID+
                                   " WHERE '"+header+"'='"+key+"'").substring(5));
    }

    /**
     * get the column header names from Fusion Table
     *
     * @returns {array}    [header, header, ...]
     */
    function getFusionHeaders(){
      var headers = [];
      var result = fusionRequest("get", "DESCRIBE "+FUSION_ID).split(/\n/);
        for (var i in result){
        result[i] = result[i].split(/,/); 
        headers.push(result[i][1]);  
      }  
      headers.splice(0, 1);
      headers.splice(headers.length-1, 1);
      return headers;  
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a record in the Fusion Table
     *
     * @params  {string}  rowid  the ID of a Fusion table row
     */
    function deleteFusionRow(rowid){  
       fusionRequest("post", "DELETE FROM "+FUSION_ID+" WHERE ROWID = '"+rowid+"'");  
    }

    /**
     * The get or post request to the Fusion API 
     *
     * @params  {string}  reqMethod  get or post
     * @params  {string}  sql        String  A sgl type request see http://goo.gl/aVP3B
     * @returns {integer}            Fusion rowid useful for unique ID of record
     */
    function fusionRequest(method, sql) {

      var url = "https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query";

      if (USE_OAUTH){
        var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_();   
      }else{
        var fetchArgs = new Object();
        fetchArgs.headers = {"Authorization": "GoogleLogin auth=" + getAuthToken_()};
      } 
      fetchArgs.method = method; 

      if( method == 'get' ) {
        url += '?sql='+sql;
        fetchArgs.payload = null;
      } else{
        fetchArgs.payload = 'sql='+sql;
      } 
      return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getContentText(); 
    }

    /**
     * @private for OAuth
     */
    function googleOAuth_() {
      var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService('fusion');
      oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/"+
                 "OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query");
      oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
      oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
      return {oAuthServiceName:'fusion', oAuthUseToken:"always"};
    }


    /**
     * @private for client Auth
     * @returns String(auth token for a user)
     */ 
    function getAuthToken_() {

      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", {
          method: "post",
          payload: "accountType=GOOGLE" +
                   "&Email=" + ScriptProperties.getProperty('CUSTOMER_KEY') + 
                   "&Passwd=" + encodeURIComponent(ScriptProperties.getProperty('CUSTOMER_SECRET'))+ 
                   "&service=fusiontables" +
                   "&Source=testing"
      });
      var responseStr = response.getContentText();
      responseStr = responseStr.slice(responseStr.search("Auth=") + 5, responseStr.length);
      responseStr = responseStr.replace(/\n/g, "");
      return responseStr;
    }


    /**
     * Used to authenticate to Fusion Tables
     * Run it twice!
     */
    function doOAuth(){
      var method = 'get';
      var sql = "SHOW TABLES";  
      Logger.log(fusionRequest(method,sql));
    }

    var USE_OAUTH = true; 
    var FUSION_ID = ScriptProperties.getProperty('FUSION_ID');
```

Comment: Make sure that the data you want to `UPDATE` or `INSERT` is correctly escape. It's probably the easiest way to use the function  `encodeURIComponent()` for every query you run, e.g. use `encodeURIComponent(sql)` in your function `fusionRequest()`.

Comment: For the special characteres , ' " and \ the workaround Odi wrote does not work. The SQL statement understand those characteres as SQL commands. So it is necessary to replace does characteres for others or a code when updating to the fusion table, ans decode that when getting the string back from the fusion table.